# Ember could not get select value from template to component

Tags: select, ember.js

I'm struggling with this. I would like to pass a select value from template to component.
Here is my template

```
<select name="bank" class="form-control" id="sel1" onchange={{action "updateValue" value="bank"}}>
        {{#each banks as |bank|}}
        <option value={{bank.id}}>{{bank.name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
        {{log bank.id}}
      </select>
```

And here is my component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
  banks: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('bank');
  }),
  didUpdate() {
    const banques = this.get('banks');
    const hash = [];
    banques.forEach(function(banque) {
      hash.push(banque.get('name'));
    });
    Ember.$(".typeahead_2").typeahead({ source: hash });
  },
  actions: {
    expand: function() {
      Ember.$('.custom-hide').attr('style', 'display: block');
      Ember.$('.custom-display').attr('style', 'display: none');
    },
        updateValue(selectedValue) {
      this.set('bank.id', selectedValue);
     },
      login() {
        console.log(this.get('bank.id'));


    }
  }
});
```

And i've got this beautiful error : **Property set failed: object in path "bank" could not be found or was destroyed.**

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: This is just a extract of my template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `value` attribute then you need to specify correct property name to be retrieved from the first argument(`event`). in your case you just mentioned `bank` - which was not found in `event` object. that's the reason for that error.

```
onchange={{action "updateValue" value="target.value"}}
```

inside component

```
updateValue(selectedValue) {
  this.set('bank.id', selectedValue);
 },
```

Comment: so i need to change my component too to get target.value and not bank ?

Comment: If you are doing just set alone then you can use mut helper and you dont need to define `updateValue` function . ie. `onchange={{action (mut bank.id) value="target.value"}}`

Comment: Updated my answers with required `updateValue` function code too

Comment: Iv'e made it like you told me but it still have the same error. BTW thanks for the help !

Comment: `bank.id` is the problem, I thought you are having property `bank:{id:''}` inside the component ? Are you having it ? include the component remaining code too

Comment: i've just update my post to add the complete component

Comment: Which property you want to store the seleced bank.id? I will prepare sample twiddle for better demo

Comment: Yes i would like to store the bank.id. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6ecb9c214190687afece007f920972ae?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) . Your problem is you have not define property in component to hold the selected item.

Comment: Okay i didn't get it at first now i see ! Perfect it work thank you !!